# Node.js - How do I retrieve the value of an element within an object/array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I am not sure if I have used the correct terminology within the title, but here is the raw result that I want to retrieve data from.

```
{ items:
   [ { name: 'keydose',
       keys: 69,
       cid: 0,
       $created': '2015-06-21T19:20:38.833Z',
   '   $updated': '2015-06-21T19:20:38.833Z' } ] }
```

This is created via the use of the twitch-irc-db module with the twitch-irc library for node.js, the output above is received by doing this:

```
db.where('users', {name: user.username}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I've tried using console.log(result.items.cid), console.log(result.items.cid[0]) and console.log(result.items.cid.valueOf()) to get the value of cid from the database but I have no clue what else to try, I've been googling for a long time and just can't find anything.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to look at the structure. An Object will start with an `{` and an Array will start with a `[`. When you see an Object, you can use `.propertyName` to access `propertyName`. For an Array, you will of course need to use an index to choose one of the objects within the Array.

So here is your response object;

```
{ items:
   [ { name: 'keydose',
       keys: 69,
       cid: 0,
       $created': '2015-06-21T19:20:38.833Z',
       $updated': '2015-06-21T19:20:38.833Z' } ] }
```

We can do `result.items[0]` to access the first Object within the array that `items` is a reference to. To get `cid`, we would use `result.items[0].cid`.

Typically, if you expect items to be more than one item, you would iterate over them with a `forEach`, or a `for` loop or a library-specific method. Using `forEach`, you can do:

```
result.items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.cid);
});
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch, is there any chance you'd know how to do an if statement for if console.log(result); is empty? For example, if there isn't anything in the database under that person's name. I'm wanting to automatically insert data into the database for users that don't have any as soon as they join the IRC channel, so therefore I need to check if they do or not.

Comment: @Keydose you can do `if (!result) { ... }`. If you want to do something either way, you could do `if (result) { ... } else { ... }` and in the else, you would handle them not being in the db.

Comment: Thank you so much! Before coming to Stack Overflow I'd spent hours trying to figure it out and hopelessly scouring Google for an answer. You've helped make my introduction to the community a very positive start and I'm glad to have joined this site :)

Comment: @Keydose You're more than welcome. It's a great community. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: `result.items` is an Array (Brackets `[]` mean Array in JS). Google -> `javascript arrays`

To get the `cid` of the first item:

```
result.items[0].cid
```

To get an array of all `cid`s:

```
result.items.map(function (item) {
  return item.cid
})
```

Or if you want to do sth with every item:

```
result.items.forEach(function (item) {
  // Do stuff!
})
```